# How to retrieve JSON multi data with AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking Library with Swift.
When I retrieve single data json like [{a:"xxx",b:"yyy"}] , it is succeeded.
But when I retrieve multi data json like [{a:"xxx",b:"yyy"},{a:"mmm",b:"nnn"}], it failed.

```
    let manager:AFHTTPRequestOperationManager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    let serializer:AFJSONRequestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
    manager.requestSerializer = serializer
    manager.GET("http://www.test.com/member.json", parameters: nil,
        success: {(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responsObject: AnyObject!) in
            let responsDict = responsObject as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        })
```

I think I should change type of responsObject Dictionary to something else.
But I have no idea.

Would you give me advice please.

Comment: Your second "multi data" seems to be a array at first level instead of a dictionary.

Comment: [{a:"xxx",b:"yyy"},{a:"mmm",b:"nnn"}] is not valid JSON. Can you post the actual JSON you are getting back please

Comment: [{"a":"xxx","b":"yyy"},{"a":"mmm","b":"nnn"}]

Comment: Should I format JSON like this?  members:[{"a":"xxx","b":"yyy"},{"a":"mmm","b":"nnn"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following example to see what you are missing:

```
manager.GET( "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=",
    parameters: nil,
    success: {
        operation, responseObject in

        if let quote = responseObject?.objectForKey("query")?.objectForKey("results")?.objectForKey("quote") as? NSDictionary {

            let symbol = quote.objectForKey("Symbol") as? String
            let lastTradePriceOnly = quote.objectForKey("LastTradePriceOnly") as? String

            println("results: \(symbol) @ \(lastTradePriceOnly)")
        } else {
            println("no quote")
        }
    },
    failure: {
        operation, error in

        println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    })
```

Comment: What if I wanna get "execution-start-time" on https://query.yahooapis.com?  In my case, I changed my JSON format to like this. http://score-sheet.herokuapp.com/api/members/all.json . I would like to get list of Members.

Comment: Thank you all!!! I get it. My format of JSON was wrong. I should change format  like this.  {"query": {"members":[{"a":"xxx","b":"yyy"},{"a":"mmm","b":"nnn"}] } }